# how do i access a return value from a jQuery function

Tags: jquery, function, global-variables, local-variables

I'm wondering how how access returned values from a jQuery function. I know the basic way with a javascript function like so: "var myVar=myFunction();"

But can anyone please show me how I would do it with a jQuery function like this? If i was looking to access the mousePosX and mousePosY? I just don't see a function name to reference. Thanks in advance as always!

```
    $("#demoCanvas").mousemove(function(event){
        mousePosX = event.pageX;
        mousePosY = event.pageY;
        return mousePosX;
        return mousePosY;
    });//end mousemove()
```

Comment: where do you want to access those variables?

Comment: I want to use the values for another click function. I guess I could just also grab the positions in the click() like i did in this mousemove(), but now its just a curiosity thing, as it may help shape how I write this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use an object for that purpose:

```
        function pointer(){
            this.x;
            this.y;
            this.set = function(x,y){this.x=x;this.y=y;}
        }
        var p = new pointer();
        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
            p.set(e.pageX,e.pageY);
        });
```

You can access the position like this:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("body").append(p.x+" "+p.y+"</br>");
});
```

Comment: Yeah that's an easy way to avoid repeating code. Thanks Kamen.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of callbacks.

You pretty much *don't* access values returned from an event callback. These callbacks run asynchronously from the rest of your code, so any processing that depends on, say `mousePosX` and `mousePosY`, needs to happen *inside the callback.* The callback function you pass to `mousemove` should fully express the code that should run when that event fires.

Here's a simple example: you might want to pass `mousePosX` to another function, so that function can do something with it. The callback does not return `mousePosX`; *it calls the other function.*

```
$("#demoCanvas").mousemove(function(event){
    var mousePosX = event.pageX;

    someOtherFunction(mousePosX);
});
```

Comment: Ok so basically what you're saying is when using a callback like this, I can bring in functions to play with mousePosX, but there's no way to bring mousePosX out to mess with. For a return value like that I have to use normal functions?

Comment: thanks Matt. Live and learn. I thought i was just missing something since I couldn't find a way to do it.